# Rviz teleop Interactive markers errors

Tags: ros, rviz, turtlebot, ros-electric, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running electric ros turtlebot on oneiric (Workstation in network Turtlebot ROS Master, Interactive Markers in Tutorial after "No errors" Running Marker Server, gives this:

```
(rviz:7298): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[ INFO] [1335238890.658620605]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1335238890.658777489]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1335238890.658815534]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1335238891.264550633]: Loading general config from [/home/ross/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1335238891.264919986]: Loading display config from [/home/ross/.rviz/display_config]

[ INFO] [1335238891.294179575]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.

The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.

This probably reflects a bug in the program.

The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 22 error_code 9 request_code 137 minor_code 3)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Any suggestions to troubleshoot & fix?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32432/rviz-teleop-interactive-markers-errors/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing Oneiric I had some annoying GTK warnings, too. A brief search on the internet showed that this was an Ubuntu problem and I also found an easy fix. However, I haven't tested RViz on that system and I don't know, if fixing that GTK warning will resolve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0